# Equivolume financial chart in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, charts, financial

Can't find anywhere a Matlab code to plot Equivolume bars, does anybody knows how to?
http://www.armsinsider.com/education/armsonthemarket/equiv_chart.asp
Thanks, Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function based on boxplot as suggested by [zellus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776713/equivolume-financial-chart-in-matlab/3782273#3782273):

```
function hh = equivolumechart(x,w)
% EQUIVOLUMECHART - simple equivolume chart based on barplot
% x - 2xn high/low values, w - volume (box width)

h = boxplot(x,'width',w);
% make median unvisible
for ii=1:size(h,2)
    set(h(6,ii),'visible','off')
end
if nargout>0, hh = h; end 

end
```

Example:

```
a = randi(10,2,10);
w = randi(10,1,10)/10;
equivolumechart(a,w)
```

The function can be rewritten using patches, but this one works pretty well.

You probably can use [CANDLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/finance/candle.html) function from Financial Toolbox setting width to patch objects, but I don't have the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

[boxplot](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15053-simple-box-whiskers-plot-for-those-who-dont-have-the-statistics-toolbox) might be a starting point to create your own *equivplot*.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [ ] = equivolumechart(highs, lows, volumes)
    % calculate pos of each box
    pos = zeros(length(volumes), 1);    
    for i=2:length(volumes)
        pos(i) = pos(i-1) + (volumes(i-1) + volumes(i))/2;
    end

    h = boxplot([highs'; lows'], 'width', volumes', 'positions', pos);
end
```

The key is to find the position of each box. Since 'positions' defines the vertical center line of boxes, the distance between two boxes should be (volumes(i-1) + volumes(i))/2